# Which version of the name こうき means happiness?

Tags: meaning, names

. Hey, everyone! I named my main character Kouki, but I'm unsure of the meaning of the variation I'm using (幸輝). I want to make sure that the one I use means "happiness." Could you please help?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do in detail? If you know nothing about kanji, how did you come up with that name, and how did you know it has a meaning of "happiness"? By the way [this page](https://b-name.jp/%E8%B5%A4%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E5%90%8D%E5%89%8D%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/all/%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%8D/?o=yomi) is a list of >800 names that can be read "Kouki".

Comment: @naturo The variant I was using is 幸輝, which I found on BehindTheNames. And its meaning changes depending on the kanji used. I wanted one that meant happiness because my character's mother called him her "happiness in the flesh" when she was pregnant with him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こうき (Kouki) can be divided into two syllables "Kou" and "Ki", and each sound can have many corresponding kanji. Thus there are literally hundreds of possible combinations that can be read Kouki. Among them, yes, 幸 (Kou) is a common kanji meaning "happiness". 倖 is a less common variant. The second kanji that corresponds to "Ki" is arbitrary, but the one you chose (輝 = "shine/glow") seems reasonable and common to me.

Comment: If I used the character 貴 in place of 輝, would the name then mean "precious happiness?"

Comment: @JeremiahTDK Yes, sort of, but individual meanings of kanji are not that important to us as long as person names are concerned and common kanji are used. I suppose you don't worry about the literal meaning of "Johnson", "Smith" or "White" every time you see them.

Comment: Thanks. Next time, I should keep looking instead of making a fool of myself.

Comment: I found another version of こうき composed of the characters 幸 (for happiness) and 生 (for life or birth.)  If these characters came together, would the meaning be "happiness is born" or "living happiness?" I just want to be sure.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK No, you cannot parse it as a grammatical Japanese phrase like that. It's just two random kanji put next to each other to form a name. As I said, it usually makes little sense to worry about the meaning of names. If you insist, 幸生 means "happinessborn".

Comment: I just wanted to review it to make sure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will be very glad to know that you can solve this problem without help from other people. First go to an online name dictionary and find all the "kouki"s:

https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?2MDJ%A4%B3%A4%A6%A4%AD

Then go through the list and check the meanings of the kanji names using an online dictionary.

Comment: I found two variations: 光嬉 and 好嬉. Would the first mean "shining happiness" and the second mean "great happiness/joy?"

Comment: 光 is light, and 好 means to like something, but I don't know the second kanji in those compounds.

Comment: The version I was originally using was 幸輝. What would the compound meaning of these characters be?